How can I troubleshoot my react multistep form back button that does not work correctly?
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaAngleLeft, FaAngleRight, FaRegPaperPlane } from 
"react-icons/fa6";
import { FileUpload, ParentInfo, StudentInfo } from "..";
import "./multistepForm.css";

const MultistepForm = () => {
const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
stdName: "",
stdMiddleName: "",
stdSurname: "",
stdGender: "",
stdPOB: "",
stdDOB: "",
fatherName: "",
motherName: "",
gradeLevel: "",
grade: "",
// Parent Info
prtName: "",
prtMiddleName: "",
prtSurname: "",
prtNational: "",
prtCountry: "",
prtState: "",
prtCity: "",
prtEmail: "",
prtPhone: "",
prtIDType: "",
prtIDNum: "",
// Files
prtIDImg: "",
stdTranscript: "",
stdImg: "",
});
function next() {
setStep((i) => {
  if (i >= FormHeaders.length - 1) return i;
  return i + 1;
});
}
function back() {
setStep((i) => {
  if (i <= 0) return i;
  return i - 1;
});
}
function onSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
e.preventDefault();
if (step !== FormHeaders.length - 1) return next();
alert("Submission completed");
}
const FormHeaders = [
"Student Information",
"Parent Information",
"Upload Files",
];

const StepDisplay = () => {
if (step === 0) {
  return <StudentInfo formData={formData} setFormData= 
{setFormData} />;
} else if (step === 1) {
  return <ParentInfo formData={formData} setFormData= 
{setFormData} />;
} else {
  return <FileUpload formData={formData} setFormData= 
{setFormData} />;
}
};
return (
<div className="form">
  <h2 className="form-title">Online Application</h2>
  <div className="progressbar">
    <div
      style={{
        width: step === 0 ? "33.3%" : step === 1 ? "66.6%" : 
"100%",
      }}
    ></div>
  </div>
  <div className="form-container">
    <h1 className="form-header">{FormHeaders[step]}</h1>
    <div className="form-body">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} action="#">
        {StepDisplay()}
        <div className="form-footer">
          {step !== 0 &&
            <button className="form-btn btn" onClick={back}>
              <FaAngleLeft />
            </button>
          }
          <button className="form-btn btn" type="submit">
            {step === FormHeaders.length - 1 ? (
              <i>
                <FaRegPaperPlane />
              </i>
            ) : (
              <i>
                <FaAngleRight />
              </i>
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
};

export default MultistepForm;

I am building a multistep form with ReactJS and Vanilla JS and I ran into a problem with my Back button. The form has 3 pages and the back button works fine until I get to the last page, I cannot go back anymore (On page 2, I can still go back to page 1, but once I get to page 3, I cannot go back to page 2 as the back button stops working).
It does not display any error.
I have tried multiple ways to define the back function, but the problem is still the same.
It was working perfectly fine, until I added the onSubmit function (I am not very sure about it).

It seems you may have only given a snippet of the code. For example, there are references to MultistepForm, step, StudentInfo, etc. which have not been defined.

They are defined above the function, it would be very long if I included the whole file.

I published the whole file

maybe simplify a bit.
a switch statement might be a good idea for step display
  const StepDisplay = () => {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return <StudentInfo formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
      case 1:
        return <ParentInfo formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
      default:
        return <FileUpload formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
    }
  }

combine all your step logic into one function
  const handleNavigation = (action) => {
    if (action === "next" && step < FormHeaders.length - 1) {
      setStep(step + 1);
    } else if (action === "back" && step > 0) {
      setStep(step - 1);
    } else if (action === "submit") {
      alert("Submission completed");
    }
  };

so your submit would now look like
 const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (step !== FormHeaders.length - 1) {
      handleNavigation("next");
    } else {
      handleNavigation("submit");
    }
  };

finally add your new functions to your render
 return (
    <div className="form">
      <h2 className="form-title">Online Application</h2>
      <div className="progressbar">
        <div style={{ width: `${(step + 1) * 33.3}%` }}></div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-container">
        <h1 className="form-header">{FormHeaders[step]}</h1>
        <div className="form-body">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit} action="#">
            {StepDisplay()}
            <div className="form-footer">
              {step !== 0 && (
                <button className="form-btn btn" onClick={() => handleNavigation("back")}>
                  <FaAngleLeft />
                </button>
              )}
              <button className="form-btn btn" type="submit">
                {step === FormHeaders.length - 1 ? <FaRegPaperPlane /> : <FaAngleRight />}
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


Thank you for the simplification. It was very helpful.

Your back button does not have a type attribute and when clicked, will implicitly submit the form, causing the onSubmit() function to fire. So on page 3, the step value is set to 1 in back() but then next() is called in onSubmit(), causing the value to go back to 2 straight away, making it seem like nothing happened.
To fix this, you could consider setting type="button" on the back <button> so that it does not cause a form submission:


const { useState } = React;

var t=n(React),e={DefaultContext:{color:void 0,size:void 0,className:void 0,style:void 0,attr:void 0}}
;e.IconContext=React.createContext(e.DefaultContext);var r=["attr","size","title"];function n(t){
return t&&t.__esModule?t:{default:t}}function o(t,e){if(null==t)return{};var r,n,o=c(t,e)
;if(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols){var l=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(t);for(n=0;n<l.length;n++)r=l[n],
e.indexOf(r)>=0||Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(t,r)&&(o[r]=t[r])}return o}function c(t,e){
if(null==t)return{};var r,n,o={},c=Object.keys(t);for(n=0;n<c.length;n++)r=c[n],e.indexOf(r)>=0||(o[r]=t[r]);return o}
function l(){return l=Object.assign?Object.assign.bind():function(t){for(var e=1;e<arguments.length;e++){
var r=arguments[e];for(var n in r)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(r,n)&&(t[n]=r[n])}return t},
l.apply(this,arguments)}function a(t,e){var r=Object.keys(t);if(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols){
var n=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(t);e&&(n=n.filter((function(e){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(t,e).enumerable
}))),r.push.apply(r,n)}return r}function i(t){for(var e=1;e<arguments.length;e++){
var r=null!=arguments[e]?arguments[e]:{};e%2?a(Object(r),!0).forEach((function(e){u(t,e,r[e])
})):Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors?Object.defineProperties(t,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(r)):a(Object(r)).forEach((function(e){
Object.defineProperty(t,e,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(r,e))}))}return t}function u(t,e,r){
return(e=s(e))in t?Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:r,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):t[e]=r,t}
function s(t){var e=f(t,"string");return"symbol"==typeof e?e:String(e)}function f(t,e){
if("object"!=typeof t||null===t)return t;var r=t[Symbol.toPrimitive];if(void 0!==r){var n=r.call(t,e||"default")
;if("object"!=typeof n)return n;throw new TypeError("@@toPrimitive must return a primitive value.")}
return("string"===e?String:Number)(t)}function p(e){return e&&e.map(((e,r)=>t.default.createElement(e.tag,i({key:r
},e.attr),p(e.child))))}function v(e){return r=>t.default.createElement(d,l({attr:i({},e.attr)},r),p(e.child))}
function d(n){var c=e=>{var c,{attr:a,size:u,title:s}=n,f=o(n,r),p=u||e.size||"1em";return e.className&&(c=e.className),
n.className&&(c=(c?c+" ":"")+n.className),t.default.createElement("svg",l({stroke:"currentColor",fill:"currentColor",
strokeWidth:"0"},e.attr,a,f,{className:c,style:i(i({color:n.color||e.color},e.style),n.style),height:p,width:p,
xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"}),s&&t.default.createElement("title",null,s),n.children)}
;return void 0!==e.IconContext?t.default.createElement(e.IconContext.Consumer,null,(t=>c(t))):c(e.DefaultContext)}
function FaAngleLeft(t){return v({tag:"svg",attr:{viewBox:"0 0 320 512"},child:[{tag:"path",attr:{
d:"M41.4 233.4c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3l160 160c12.5 12.5 32.8 12.5 45.3 0s12.5-32.8 0-45.3L109.3 256 246.6 118.6c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3s-32.8-12.5-45.3 0l-160 160z"
},child:[]}]})(t)}function FaAngleRight(t){return v({tag:"svg",attr:{viewBox:"0 0 320 512"},child:[{tag:"path",attr:{
d:"M278.6 233.4c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.8 0 45.3l-160 160c-12.5 12.5-32.8 12.5-45.3 0s-12.5-32.8 0-45.3L210.7 256 73.4 118.6c-12.5-12.5-12.5-32.8 0-45.3s32.8-12.5 45.3 0l160 160z"
},child:[]}]})(t)}function FaRegPaperPlane(t){return v({tag:"svg",attr:{viewBox:"0 0 512 512"},child:[{tag:"path",attr:{
d:"M16.1 260.2c-22.6 12.9-20.5 47.3 3.6 57.3L160 376V479.3c0 18.1 14.6 32.7 32.7 32.7c9.7 0 18.9-4.3 25.1-11.8l62-74.3 123.9 51.6c18.9 7.9 40.8-4.5 43.9-24.7l64-416c1.9-12.1-3.4-24.3-13.5-31.2s-23.3-7.5-34-1.4l-448 256zm52.1 25.5L409.7 90.6 190.1 336l1.2 1L68.2 285.7zM403.3 425.4L236.7 355.9 450.8 116.6 403.3 425.4z"
},child:[]}]})(t)};

const FileUpload = () => "FileUpload";
const ParentInfo = () => "ParentInfo";
const StudentInfo = () => "StudentInfo";

const MultistepForm = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    stdName: "",
    stdMiddleName: "",
    stdSurname: "",
    stdGender: "",
    stdPOB: "",
    stdDOB: "",
    fatherName: "",
    motherName: "",
    gradeLevel: "",
    grade: "",
    // Parent Info
    prtName: "",
    prtMiddleName: "",
    prtSurname: "",
    prtNational: "",
    prtCountry: "",
    prtState: "",
    prtCity: "",
    prtEmail: "",
    prtPhone: "",
    prtIDType: "",
    prtIDNum: "",
    // Files
    prtIDImg: "",
    stdTranscript: "",
    stdImg: "",
  });
  function next() {
    setStep((i) => {
      if (i >= FormHeaders.length - 1) return i;
      return i + 1;
    });
  }
  function back() {
    setStep((i) => {
      if (i <= 0) return i;
      return i - 1;
    });
  }
  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (step !== FormHeaders.length - 1) return next();
    alert("Submission completed");
  }
  const FormHeaders = [
    "Student Information",
    "Parent Information",
    "Upload Files",
  ];

  const StepDisplay = () => {
    if (step === 0) {
      return <StudentInfo formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
    } else if (step === 1) {
      return <ParentInfo formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
    } else {
      return <FileUpload formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="form">
      <h2 className="form-title">Online Application</h2>
      <div className="progressbar">
        <div
          style={{
            width: step === 0 ? "33.3%" : step === 1 ? "66.6%" : "100%",
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-container">
        <h1 className="form-header">{FormHeaders[step]}</h1>
        <div className="form-body">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit} action="#">
            {StepDisplay()}
            <div className="form-footer">
              {step !== 0 && (
                <button className="form-btn btn" onClick={back} type="button">
                  <FaAngleLeft />
                </button>
              )}
              <button className="form-btn btn" type="submit">
                {step === FormHeaders.length - 1 ? (
                  <i>
                    <FaRegPaperPlane />
                  </i>
                ) : (
                  <i>
                    <FaAngleRight />
                  </i>
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<MultistepForm />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



